# A question on List of data

Tags: list-manipulation

Hope you are doing well and have good times.

My question comes back to dealing with a list of data and extracting points from it.

I have explored my problem within a Mathematica code and I would appreciate it if you could help me to overcome this problem.

Thank you very much and best regards.

We want to specify the points (x,y) that correspond to the conditions:2 x^3 + y^2/2 > 1 && y - x^3/3 < 0. So we can use RegionPlot command.

```
RegionPlot[2 x^3 + y^2/2 > 1 && y - x^3/3 < 0, {x, -1, 0}, {y, -2, -1}]
```

Now, we want to use a For loop in order to find the corresponding (x,y) points.

`SetDirectory["C:\\Users"]; data1 = OpenWrite["data1.txt", FormatType -> OutputForm]; For[x = -1, x <= 0, x = x + 0.02,  For[y = -2, y <= -1, y = y + 0.02,  If[2 x^3 + y^2/2 > 1 && y - x^3/3 < 0, Write[data1, x "  " , y]]]] d1 = Import["data1.txt", "Table"]; ListPlot[d1] Close[data1];`

The region obtained by the above For loop is the same as what RegionPlot has done.

Now my question is, How can I pick each (x,y) point from the list d1 (according to the intervals -1<= x <=0 and -2<=y<=-1) and then substitute the point into a function of x and y for example f(x,y)=x^2+2y and then find the value of f(x,y) for each point?

In other words, I want to find the values of f(x,y) for all the points shown in the Figure provided by ListPlot[d1].

Answer (score 2):

```
xValues = Range[-1, 0, 0.02];
yValues = Range[-2, -1, 0.02];

xyAll = Flatten[Outer[{#1, #2} &, xValues, yValues], 1];

cons = 2 x^3 + y^2/2 > 1 && y - x^3/3 < 0;
```

[`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) the points that satisfy the constraints

```
xyPairs = Select[xyAll, 
   2 #[[1]]^3 + #[[2]]^2/2 > 1 && #[[2]] - #[[1]]^3/3 < 0 &];
```

Overlaying the points on the [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html)

```
RegionPlot[cons, {x, -1, 0}, {y, -2, -1},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "y"}),
 BoundaryStyle -> None,
 Epilog -> {Text[Style[cons, 14], {-0.6, -1.3}],
   Red, AbsolutePointSize[2], Point[xyPairs]}]
```

[image]

For the function

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + 2 y
```

Generating 3D data

```
data = {#[[1]], #[[2]], f @@ #} & /@ xyPairs;
```

Overlaying the points on the Plot3D

```
Show[
 Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -1, 0}, {y, -2, -1},
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Evaluate@cons]],
 Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[3], Point[data]}],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "y", "f"})]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice and helpful answer, Thank you so much Bob

Comment: `xyAll = Tuples[{xValues, yValues}]` would be simpler.